# How to bind event to JSignature focus

Tags: jsignature

I am using JSignature and am trying to figure out how to get events to fire when the signature gets focus and when it loses focus.

Binding to the change event works but focus, mousedown etc does not fire.

Would appreciate any guidance if anybody knows how to do this please

```
$('.jsig').jSignature({format:"image/jpeg"}) // inits the jSignature widget.
$(".jsig").jSignature.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
    alert("mousedown");
});
$(".jsig").jSignature.bind('focus', function(e) {
    alert("focus");
});

var j=$(".jsig").jSignature;

$(".jsig").bind('change', function(e) {
    var d = $(e.target).jSignature("getData", "native");
    document.getElementById('st').value=d.length+'.'+d[0].x.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, the answer appears to be add an onmouseenter to the div JSignature attaches to

```
<div id="jsig" class="jsig" onmouseenter="dosomething();"></div>

<script>
function dosomething(){
    alert("Here");
}
```

Can then use the bind change to see if there is a signature or onmouseleave.